# Can't see or read commands

Tags: interface

I just found Blender.
Is it possible to change the background color.I'm old and it's impossible to read the commands. Any help or hints would be appreciated.
Thank you.
Don

Comment: A little more information on exactly what you are trying to do would be nice. I think you are looking for the User Preferences, press Ctrl+Alt+U to open them, and go to Themes

Answer (score 4):

[image]

You may also find it useful to change the general size of font.  In Blender User Preferences change the DPI to 108 as indicated above. This will make the font bigger than the default. Suit to your personal needs.