# Interface text is tiny on high resolution screen

Tags: windows

Blender fills the screen but the text is all tiny. Too small to read with any ease at all.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46257/cant-see-or-read-commands/46266#46266

Answer (score 0):

Go to file, user preferences (or use the hotkey, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>.

[image]

Then go to the system settings, and change the DPI. This will change the text size.

[image]

If that's not enough, you may have to change the virtual pixel mode to double.

[image]